# Clang with minggw not works

Tags: c++, mingw, clang, codeblocks

I have Windows XP and Mingw with gcc 4.7.1. I download clang from http://www.llvm.org/releases/download.html#3.1, Experimental Clang Binaries for Mingw32/x86 to d:\clang. I try call clang++.exe --help but is black console screen, no messages and after while is error. Also if I use Code::Blocks nightly build to build Hellow world with clang is error. Why?